# Find records that do not have related records in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables (Orders, OrderItems) that are related based on a column OrderID.  I need to find all Orders that do not have any OrderItems.

Comment: That's an *easy* one!  In fact, one of my support guys came in yesterday and asked the exact same question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We use JOIN to find related data. To find data without any related data, we can use an [anti-join](https://mode.com/blog/anti-join-examples/).

The following joins the tables, then selects those without any order items. This tends to be more efficient that a `WHERE id NOT IN (...)` style query.

```
select *
from
    Orders O
    left outer join OrderItems I
    on I.OrderId = O.Id
where
    I.Id is null
```

Comment: Aaron - I can imagine ways that a left outer join would be more efficient but do you have a specific reference for your assertion? I'd probably avoid using this construct because of the additional complexity but it might be appropriate (for me) for large datasets if there is a clear performance difference.

Comment: I do not have a specific reference; it is just an assertion I've heard from colleagues and one that I have often found to be true in my own experiences. This solution is not necessarily the best for every case, so it is best to try each and check out their respective execution plans and decide which is best from there.

Comment: After some searching, I found a lot of agreement with my thoughts on the subject. Here is a relevant link: http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/using-joins-instead-of-sub-queries-a-case-study/

Comment: Thanks Aaron!  Very useful reference - I appreciate the effort it took to look it up.

Answer (score 7):

```
Select * From Orders Where OrderID not in (Select Distinct OrderID From OrderItems)
```

Answer (score 2):

try with LEFT EXCEPTION JOIN

```
select *
from Orders
LEFT EXCEPTION JOIN OrderItems ON ...
```

Comment: I believe that EXCEPTION joins are NOT supported by most databases.